# Delete record from file C++

Tags: c++, file-io, record, file-pointer, delete-record

I'm working on a simple database console application in C++ for adding, editing and deleting records in a .dat file. I have the addition and modification down, I'm just finding it hard to understand the concept of deletion in this scenario. Below is how I write a record.

Write record

```
fh.seekp(num*sizeof(customerObj),ios::beg); // Move the write pointer to where rec is
fh.write((char*)&customerObj,sizeof(customerObj)); // Write updated rec
```

Any ideas how instead of `write()` I could have something equivalent to `delete()`... or is it not that simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ don't have functions to delete parts of files. Many operating systems don't either.

Possible options:

1. If this is the last record, truncate the file. If not, move (=copy) all records after it, overwriting it, then truncate. Alternatively you could move (=copy) the last record to it and then truncate.
2. Create an extra file and copy to it all records before this and after this record. Then delete the old file and rename the new file.
3. Mark the record as unused. When writing new records check if you have any unused locations and use them first.
4. Use a file per record.

Comment: Think I'll go with marking the records as deleted, probably the easiest! Thanks :)

Comment: Number 3 gets my vote. Fairly easy to implement and fastest by far.

Comment: Note that this all supposes that records have a fixed length.  Otherwise, the only real solution is 2.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, options 1b and 3 won't work with variable-length records.

Comment: @JamesKanze You could have a separate file which indicates unused records.

Comment: @PeterWood That doesn't change anything.  You can't overwrite a record with a longer record.

Comment: @James They're talking about deleting not modifying.

Comment: @PeterWood They're talking about marking a record as deleted, and then reusing it later.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce marker of deleted record. So instead of movement of large chunks of file you need write 1 symbol. When you need allocate new record you could iterate over already deleted and just remove marker.

Answer (score 1):

Well, deleting from files is not trivial as you cannot delete a row from a file directly. 
One approach is to read the entire file (or in bulks) and write it back without the required line. (quite robust and not efficient for large files).

Maybe if you divide you record file into smaller partitioned files than doing the above will be more efficient.

Another thing you can do is just mark a row in the file as invalid (as done in memory when deleting a pointer) and overwrite it when needed which of course depends on how you write your records but I hope you get what I mean.